# Java Alert Framework

Tags: java, frameworks, alerts

Are there any "Alert" (or Notification) frameworks in Java out there.

In my web application I would like our users to be able to configure which (of the available alerts) they would like to receive and in which (e.g via email) form.

As a simple example, a user chooses to be alerted only via email when his/her order has been shipped.

Comment: Perhaps "Notification Frameworks" would be a better title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing comes by default in Java/J2EE. However, it does NOT take much to implement. Your order processor and other processors can have listeners /observers on the processORder method. These can process the email/other notifications.

You can even have a jms message coming out of the OrderProcessor with some info about the particular notification and you send an email/otherAlert to the user after consuming the JMS message.

Answer (score 0):

We can use JMS for sending notifications to users. 
JMS producers puts the alerts in queue and producers will process the message and send to notifications to user via. email / sms and/or store in database to show the messages in user dashboards.